# Javascript return reference to array index with primitive value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I want to return a reference to to the content of an array at index x in order to be able to change the content of the array using the returned index afterwards.
Here is an example of what I mean:

```
let testArr = [1,2,3]
const someFunct = arr => {
    ...
    return {reference to arr[0], aka 1}
}
someFunct(testArr) = 0;

//should log [0,2,3]
console.log(testArr);
```

`someFunct(testArr)` should behave like `arr[0]` in this case.
 The content of the array could be anything.

Comment: ```someFunct(testArr) = 0;``` what are you trying to do here?? Also can you add the proper input and expected output

Comment: someFunct should return a reference to testArray at some index, in this case 0 - someFunct(testArr) should therfore act like testArr[0], i.e. assigning it a value would change the array to [0, 2, 3]. testArr is the input and I dont know the output

Comment: i am pretty sure this is not how u can assign a value..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think the exact implementation you are trying to achieve is possible in JavaScript.

https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600

something similar:

```
const testArr = [1,2,3]
const changeArray = (array, index, newValue) => {
    array[index] = newValue
    return array
}

changeArray(testArr, 0, 0) // evaluates to [0,2,3]
```

Comment: Thats what I feared :/ I also dont know the index beforehand, its determined by the function

Answer (score 0):

> I want to return a reference …

This is not possible, JavaScript doesn't have references as returnable values. The `someFunct(testArr) = 0;` syntax you are imagining is invalid.

Instead, take the new value as an argument:

```
function someFunct(arr, val) {
    …
    arr[0] = val;
}
someFunct(testArr, 0);
```

or return an object with a method that does the assigning:

```
function someFunct(arr) {
    …
    return {
        set(v) {
            arr[0] = v;
        }
    };
}
someFunct(testArr) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
    function arrayWrapper(arr, index, newVal) {
      let returnVal;
      if(newVal) {
        arr[index] = newVal;
        returnVal = arr;
      } else {
        const obj = { ...arr };
        returnVal = obj[index];
      }
      return returnVal;
    };

    console.log(arrayWrapper([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 5)); /// to get value at index
    console.log(arrayWrapper([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 5, 'text')); // to set value on index
```

You can use the above method to **get** as well as **set** elements to your array.
The nature of operation depends on the third parameter.

Hope this helps :)